# Close laptop cover

Tags: 10.10, laptop

I have laptop and connected display. Now i set up my ubuntu, that laptop display off, only connected display on.

How can i set my ubuntu, that it not respond, when i close cover? I want it, because i work only with connected display, and don't need laptop display on this basis i want close my laptop cover.

Answer (score 1):

Go to System -> Settings -> Power Management and there you can set what happens when you close the laptop cover.
[image]

Comment: i need close laptop cover. with this method i can't do what i want.

Answer (score 0):

Run these commands in terminal:

```
gconftool-2 --set /apps/gnome-power-manager/buttons/lid_ac --type string "nothing"
gconftool-2 --set /apps/gnome-power-manager/buttons/lid_battery --type string "nothing"
```